# How should a question with inappropriate/NSFW imagery be handled?

Tags: discussion, offensive

I think this has not been asked yet, or I could not find it.

Specifically, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37198738/mix-blend-mode-overlay-doesnt-work-on-safari) links to a fiddle containing an image of a couple of topless women among other people. The question asks about CSS and blending the image somehow. However, better images should do the job, and this could be considered rude in some cultures, specially when watching it at work.

A new user had just posted an answer (which, unfortunately, is not a real answer and should eventually be flagged as that) exposing her views on such behaviour from the OP.

IMHO, it's a totally sensible thought, although it's not fit in a Q&A format and should probably be handled here, if anywhere.

How should this be handled?

Should the question be edited? Should we be expected to edit the fiddle when moderating such issues? Or just flag the answer as.. what exactly?

I'm skipping the answer on triage, because I'd rather have the OP to edit the question on his own if they reads the answer than taking action against the new user about it.

Comment: What is "non-mock" rude, and how does it differ from "mock rude" and (plain) rude?

Comment: @Kaz - I think the OP means "mock" as in "mocking" like making fun of someone. So it's rude as in inappropriate, not rude as in insulting.

Comment: @BSMP I see. I thought it might be like character Nigel Tufnel's "mock piece" in the movie *Spinal Tap* (his composition that is influenced by (Mo)zart and Ba(ch)).

Comment: And now let the meta-effect come into effect...

Comment: Sorry, I was afk. It's a much better title after Cody Gray's edit anyway. What I originally meant to say was mock-up, meaning placeholder or something like that (and the fact that this kind of imagery should not qualify as a placeholder image). But actually the question was about NSFW and the like.

Comment: This seems to be an necessary use of inappropriate images; however, I think this question/thread is very important when applied to stackoverflow submissions regarding things such as 'filtering inappropriate images out of a set of images' or other related work.

For example, this must be done by the Google image processing team in order to flag certain images as nude, etc. 

I would think in some cases (although perhaps few, since other techniques may be used to demonstrate certain ideas) it may be arguably necessary to display such images.

Comment: @Kaz In Spinal Tap he's not saying it's a "Mock" piece like (Mo)zart + Ba(ch), he's saying "Mach" - as in (M)ozart + B(ach). Your confusion might be because with a Canadian accent (as you are) his pronounciation is like how you would say "mock" but he's British, using the proper German pronounciation of "Bach".

Answer (score 38):

There are a few different ways to proceed with this.

1. You can edit the JSFiddle link to remove the image.  If you don't have full edit privileges (2k+ rep), it will go to the suggested edit queue for review.
2. You can comment to the user explaining that the image is inappropriate.
3. If you are unsure of how to proceed with it but you think something needs to be done, you can always flag the post for a moderator using the Other flag.  Just explain what's wrong and what you think a moderator should do.

In this case, I went ahead and created a new fiddle link removing that image and commented to the OP to be mindful of the content they are using in their code examples.

Comment: Right. I just thought it felt wrong to call for a moderator if I knew how to proceed, and that's why I created the meta question, for next time's sake. Thanks!

Comment: I find it ironic that the offending picture has been edited away by someone with a booby for an avatar.

Comment: @MrLister bluefeet's booby wouldn't offend anybody, but I appreciate the irony

Comment: Can/should the edit history be scrubbed, too?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better for the user to edit the post instead of flagging it? I know some similar flags would just get declined with basically "you can fix it on your own."

Comment: @hichris123 Yes, they can edit it but it would go to the suggested edit queue in this case and there is no guarantee the queue would approve it.  But I've gone ahead and added those details to the answer.   Asking a mod to step-in is not a problem if you explain why you're flagging it, etc.

Comment: wait, is Gavin Belson scrubbing the internet?